How to find the upperbound/(verify it) of the solution to this differential equation. Thanks in advance!
Let $y=f(x)$ be the solution of the differential equation $\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{x+2 y^2}{2+y^2}$ where $f(4)=0$ then which of the following are true. Options are
(A) $f^{\prime}(x) \geq 2 \forall x>4$
(B) $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x \geq 0$
(C) $\int_4^8 f(x) d x \geq 32$
(D) $\int_4^8 f(x) d x \leq 24$
To solve the above question, I first observe that dy/dx at x=4 is 2, and for any subsequent x=4+$\Delta$x we would get y=2$\Delta$x which means that dy/dx is always above 2 for any given value of x>4,
For the other part of the question (integral). I formed a triangle with the given f(4)=0, from x=4 and x=8,with minimum slope 2 ,thus we could conclude $\int_4^8 f(x) d x \geq 16$ , Now I am stuck on finding the upperbound(option D) which I cant find a way to solve.

Please read this for advice on using MathJax (not images), and showing your research before asking a question.

Did so, thanks! any other changes i could make?

You can obtain the upper bound by splitting the interval into four parts: On $(4,5)$ you have $f'(x) \le \frac 52$ because of
$$\frac{x+2y^2}{2+y^2} \le \frac{5+2y^2}{2+y^2} \le \frac{5+ \frac 52 y^2}{2+y^2} = \frac 52.$$
This implies (since $f(4) =0$) that $f(5) \le \frac 52$. In similar fashinon you obtain
$$f'(x) \le 3 \text{ for } x \in [5,6) \Rightarrow f(6) \le \frac{11}{2},$$
$$f'(x) \le \frac 72 \text{ for } x \in [6,7) \Rightarrow f(7) \le 9,$$
$$f'(x) \le 4 \text{ for } x \in [7,8) \Rightarrow f(8) \le 13.$$
Then you can add up everything that you know:
In the intervall $[5,6)$ there is a rectangle on the bottom of at most size $\frac 52$, on the intervall $[6,7)$ we have a rectangle of at most size $\frac{11}{2}$ and on $[7,8)$ we have a rectangle of at most size $9$.
On top of these rectangles there are triangles that are each bounded by $\frac 12$ times the maximum slope on the interval of length $1$. Hence
$$\int_4^8 f(x) dx \le \frac{5}{4} + \frac 32 + \frac 74 + 2 + \frac 52 +\frac{11}{2} + 9 = \frac{47}{2} < 24.$$
This proves the claim $(D)$ and disproves claim $(C)$ from you question which was $\int_4^8 f(x) dx \ge 32.$
